# How to make Loop?

Tags: pgfplots, loops

I need to make for loop analog in LaTeX. My code has following form

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2, font=\tiny] 
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,         
    axis y line=middle,         
    domain=-5:5,                
    restrict y to domain=-5:5,  
    xmin=-5,    xmax=5,         
    ymin=-5,    ymax=5,         
    x=0.5cm,                        
    y=0.5cm,                        
    grid=both,                  
    xtick={-5,...,5},           
    ytick={-5,...,5},           
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
    anchor=west,},
    every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
    anchor=south,},
]
\addplot[smooth,red,domain=0:2*pi,variable=\t] ({4*cos(180/pi*t)},{4*sin(180/pi*t)});
\addplot[smooth,orange,domain=0:4,variable=\r] ({r*cos(360/4)},{r*sin(360/4)});
\addplot[smooth,orange,domain=0:4,variable=\r] ({r*cos(2*360/4)},{r*sin(2*360/4)});
\addplot[smooth,orange,domain=0:4,variable=\r] ({r*cos(3*360/4)},{r*sin(3*360/4)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to write for loop to automatically make "n" lines?

Comment: Do you want an example of the syntax? Look here for a simple case: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cycle/ That website also has more complicated cases...

Comment: If you specify in your question how to make 1 line, then we can show you how to make "n" lines. If the lines are really all the same, then it's very simple.

Comment: texample.net/tikz/examples/cycle  this example was very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two nested `\foreach` loops. Since `\k` depends on `\n` you could probably reduce it to one loop. I'm not a mathematician but I think the TeX part is correct here.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\newcommand{\nMAX}{20} 
\newcommand{\kMAX}{19}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2, font=\tiny] 
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,         
    axis y line=middle,         
    domain=-5:5,                
    restrict y to domain=-5:5,  
    xmin=-5,    xmax=5,         
    ymin=-5,    ymax=5,         
    x=0.5cm,                        
    y=0.5cm,                        
    grid=both,                  
    xtick={-5,...,5},           
    ytick={-5,...,5},           
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
    anchor=west,},
    every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
    anchor=south,},
]

\foreach \n in {1, ..., \nMAX} 
    \foreach \k in {0, ..., \kMAX} 
        {
            \addplot[smooth,orange,domain=0:4,variable=\r]
                ({r*cos(\k*360/\n)},{r*sin(\k*360/\n)});
        }

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is this what you were expecting?

[image]

Comment: I get some errors from your code; perhaps you're using an earlier version of `pgfplots`?