# Using tikz foreach (in axis environment) and addplot to graph functions with changing/varying colors and linewidth

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

I want to make a tikzpicture displaying a function shifted multiple times, each time having a lighter color and line width. Using [How to make Loop?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218704/how-to-make-loop) and [Changing color in foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251300/changing-color-in-foreach) as references, I created the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      grid=major,
      xmin=-0.25,
      xmax=10,
      ymin=-0.25,
      ymax=1.25,
      width=15cm,
      height=5cm,
      ]
      
      \addplot[smooth,densely dashed,black] coordinates {(5,-0.5)(5,1.5)};
      % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218704/how-to-make-loop
      % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251300/changing-color-in-foreach
      \foreach \n in {0, ..., 8} 
      {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\clr{\n*10} % color
        \pgfmathsetmacro\lnwdth{10-\n} % color
        \addplot[smooth, blue!\clr, line width=\lnwdth pt,domain={{8-\n}:10},->] {1/((x-6+\n)*ln(x-6+\n))};
        \addplot[smooth,blue!\clr,line width=\lnwdth pt, domain={-0.25:8-\n},<-] {0};
        \addplot[mark=*,solid,blue!\clr] coordinates {(8-\n, {1/(2*ln(2))} )};
        \addplot[mark=*,solid,blue!\clr,fill=white] coordinates {(8-\n, 0)};
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

However, there are some errors (current one being `undefined control sequence \pgfkeyscurrentkey ->blue!\clr`). A comment in one of the linked posts mentioned something about `\foreach` not working in `axis` (but the 1st post I linked does use that...), and so I tried looking at [\foreach not behaving in axis environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment) and replacing `\foreach` with `pgfplotsinvokeforeach`, but that didn't work (`undefined control sequence \pgfplotsinvokeforeach`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempt using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` below, while it should not raise "undefined control sequence", will give the wrong output here...

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

123

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      grid=major,
      xmin=-0.25,
      xmax=10,
      ymin=-0.25,
      ymax=1.25,
      width=15cm,
      height=5cm,
      ]
      
      \addplot[smooth,densely dashed,black] coordinates {(5,-0.5)(5,1.5)};
      % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218704/how-to-make-loop
      % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251300/changing-color-in-foreach
      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0, ..., 8} 
      {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\clr{#1*10} % color
        \pgfmathsetmacro\lnwdth{10-#1} % color
        \addplot[smooth, blue!\clr, line width=\lnwdth pt,domain={{8-#1}:10},->] {1/((x-6+#1)*ln(x-6+#1))};
        \addplot[smooth,blue!\clr,line width=\lnwdth pt, domain={-0.25:8-#1},<-] {0};
        \addplot[mark=*,solid,blue!\clr] coordinates {(8-#1, {1/(2*ln(2))} )};
        \addplot[mark=*,solid,blue!\clr,fill=white] coordinates {(8-#1, 0)};
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

... because `\clr` and `\lnwdth` themselves are macros, which suffers from the same problem.

Use the edef trick:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

123

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      grid=major,
      xmin=-0.25,
      xmax=10,
      ymin=-0.25,
      ymax=1.25,
      width=15cm,
      height=5cm,
      ]
      
      \addplot[smooth,densely dashed,black] coordinates {(5,-0.5)(5,1.5)};
      % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218704/how-to-make-loop
      % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251300/changing-color-in-foreach
      \foreach \n in {0, ..., 8} 
      {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\clr{\n*10} % color
        \pgfmathsetmacro\lnwdth{10-\n} % color
        \edef\temp{
        \noexpand\addplot[smooth, blue!\clr, line width=\lnwdth pt,domain={{8-\n}:10},->] {1/((x-6+\n)*ln(x-6+\n))};
        \noexpand\addplot[smooth,blue!\clr,line width=\lnwdth pt, domain={-0.25:8-\n},<-] {0};
        \noexpand\addplot[mark=*,solid,blue!\clr] coordinates {(8-\n, {1/(2*ln(2))} )};
        \noexpand\addplot[mark=*,solid,blue!\clr,fill=white] coordinates {(8-\n, 0)};
        }\temp
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Documentation of edef and noexpand inside TeXbook/other books in  [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: "If for some obscure reasons it doesn't" -- what is "it" mean here?

Comment: @D.R Fixed. ----

Comment: So the first code snippet you post is not supposed to work, for the reasons you stated?

Comment: @D.R Yes. --------